# JavaScript onClick handler throwing error

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below anchor tag which is working fine.

```html
"<a href='#' title='Move' onclick='change_type(" + id +");return false;'><img height='20' width='28' src='" + images + "/move.png' alt='Move' /></a>"
```

Here is the function call

```
 function change_type(id) {
    alert(id);
}
```

I want to change this function to accept two parameters.

```html
"<a href='#' title='Move' onclick='change_type(" + id + ", '" + loan_type +"');return false;'><img height='20' width='28' src='" + images + "/move.png' alt='Move' /></a>"
```

```html
function change_type(id, type) {
        alert(id + type);
    }
```

I am getting below error. Id is int, type is string. Not sure if it matters. I removed and '' to both of them and still getting the same error

[image: error]

[image: Error1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using single quotes for a string inside the `onclick` attribute, use double quotes for enclosing the content of `onclick` itself.

```js
let id = 123, loan_type = "loan_type", images="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50";
document.write("<a href='#' title='Move' onclick=\"change_type(" + id + ", '" + loan_type +"');return false;\"><img height='20' width='28' src='" + images + "/move.png' alt='Move' /></a>");
function change_type(id, type) {
    alert(id + type);
}
```

Alternatively, use the HTML entity `&#39;` or `&apos;` for the single quotes around `loan_type` so that it is not interpreted as ending the `onclick` attribute.

```js
let id = 123, loan_type = "loan_type", images="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50";
document.write("<a href='#' title='Move' onclick='change_type(" + id + ", &#39;" + loan_type +"&#39;);return false;'><img height='20' width='28' src='" + images + "/move.png' alt='Move' /></a>");
function change_type(id, type) {
    alert(id + type);
}
```